# How to get text box value from view (ng-modal) to controller in angular js without using getElementById

Tags: angularjs

My view page :

```js
 $scope.profileupdate = function(profiledata) {
                 var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
                  
                 console.log("Firstname " + $scope.firstName + "Lastname " + $scope.lastName );
                 spinner.stop();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="profileform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstName" class="control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-modal="profile.firstName"  name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastName" class="control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-modal="profile.lastName" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                                </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="btn-signup" type="button" ng-click="profileupdate(profile)" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

I need to get the text box value from view to controller. Bet i cant get value in the controller. is there any other better way to get the data using angular JS.

Answer (score 1):

You want ng-model, not ng-modal.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ng-model then you can get it that way

see doc [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Answer (score 0):

its simple

use like

alert($scope.firstName) ;

Answer (score 0):

you passed the form data to controller 
console.log(profiledata.firstName);

if you do not pass the form value to controller get data directly
console.log($scope.profile.firstName);